# Writing data on a single line using savetxt in Python

Tags: python, file, file-io

What I want to do, is basically convert this Fortran code into Python:

```
open (1,file='file',form='formatted')       
write (1,*) na,nb
write (1,*) (a(i),i=1,na) 
write (1,*) (b(j),j=1,nb)
do i=1,na
   write (1,*) (f1(i,j),j=1,nb)
   write (1,*) (f2(i,j),j=1,nb)
enddo
```

So I thought about using savetxt. The first difficulty I found, was the first line, where na and nb should be save on the same line in the file. I've found that you can achieve this with:

```
np.savetxt("file.txt",(na,nb),fmt='%s',newline=" ")
```

The problem, is then whenever I want to write the second line as:

```
f=open("file.txt",'f')
np.savetxt(f,a,fmt='%s',newline=" ")
```

The array a gets added on the same line as na and nb, while I want it to be so on a new one. I can't figure out how to do this. I thought that with newline=" ", I just had to add " " to na,nb, but it doesn't work. Alternatively, what would be the cleanest way to write that Fortran code?

Comment: `np.savetxt` is just a shortcut.  You can take complete control over the formatting by using the normal Python `print` statements in a loop.  BTW, your Fortran code is writing to two different descriptors.  Do you need to create two files?  Do you want one row on each line?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you can use print to do that! Thanks! As for the two descriptors thing, it was a mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you one one row on each line like

```
1.23 1.23 1.23 1.23
2.34 2.34 2.34 2.34
```

then something like this should work:

```
f = open('file.txt','w')
print(na, nb, file=f)
np.savetxt(f, a.reshape(1,na), fmt='%s', delimiter=' ')
np.savetxt(f, b.reshape(1,nb), fmt='%s', delimiter=' ')
for row in range(f1.shape[0]):
  np.savetxt(f, f1[row], fmt='%s', delimiter=' ')
  np.savetxt(f, f2[row], fmt='%s', delimiter=' ')
```

`savetxt` puts one row on each line, but with a 1-D array, each element is considered a row.  Thus, I reshape it to 2-D (`reshape` costs almost nothing; it just changes the interpretation).

Comment: Great thanks! I must only point out, that you need to write for example a.reshape(1,na), rather than a.reshape(na,1). Otherwise it still prints one element of a (and b) on a different line.